# Getting Android Fragment no view found for ID

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-fragments

First of, I've checked this question has been done and have tested the solutions that are explained on this site (although I may have committed errors in doing them as there are so many possible causes for the error).

I mean solutions like the ones offered here:

[Android Fragment no view found for ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508044/android-fragment-no-view-found-for-id)

And here:

[Android Fragment : No view found for id 0x7f040034](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22761814/android-fragment-no-view-found-for-id-0x7f040034)

So, I'm explaining my particular case.

First of, I'm setting the layout like this in my fragment:

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_calendario_laboral, container, false);
        return root;
    }
```

That layout is, summarized, as it follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/principal">
[...]
</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Once the view has been created I get to call this method:

```
final Fragment thisFragment=this;
KotlinClass.Companion.setCalendarViewdateListener(calendarView,thisFragment,R.id.principal);
```

In that method of KotlinClass I get to call this function:

```
setFragment(FichajesFragment(), fragment,"Fichajes",id);
```

Being the parameter fragment the thisFragment passed to setCalendarViewdateListener function.

I've finally defined setFragment like this:

```
private fun setFragment(fragment: Fragment, fragment2: Fragment, tag: String, id: Int) {
                    val fragmentManager: FragmentManager = fragment2.activity!!.getSupportFragmentManager();
 val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
 for (activeFragment in fragmentManager.fragments) {
          fragmentTransaction.remove(activeFragment)
 }
 fragmentTransaction.add(id, fragment, tag)
 fragmentTransaction.commit()
 fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions()
 
}
```

It raises an exception when executing fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions() telling that no view found for id, refering to the principal id of the linearlayout.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, I think in your layout file you have to specify parameter:
`tools:context=".FragmentName"`

Answer (score 0):

I noticed several issues, but the main problem why your app is crashing is because of this part:

```
 val fragmentManager: FragmentManager = fragment2.activity!!.getSupportFragmentManager();
 val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
 for (activeFragment in fragmentManager.fragments) {
          fragmentTransaction.remove(activeFragment)
 }
```

Into `fragmentManager` you stored the fragmentManager that belongs to the activity that hosts the `fragment2`, in your case the fragment with the layout including the Linearlayout with `@+id/principal` id. Then in your `for` loop, you remove all the fragments that are managed by that `fragmentManager`, which means you removed the `fragment2` from it too. So when you later call:

```
fragmentTransaction.add(id, fragment, tag)
```

it can't find any view with the id `@+id/principal`, because the fragment containing that Linearlayout (`fragment2`) was just removed.

So for your code to work, remove the `for` loop and the app should not crash anymore. But the way your code samples look, I assume you want to add `FichajesFragment` as part of the `fragment2`, in which case you are using wrong `fragmentManager`; instead of the activity one, you should use the one that belongs to `fragment2`, i.e.:

```
val fragmentManager: FragmentManager = fragment2.childFragmentManager
```

One more note: I got confused by the `R.layout.activity_calendario_laboral`, but the layout is actually for the fragment, if I understood it correctly, so just so you know.